# Node Gyp Rebuild Error for Hubot-nagios4 node module

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, hubot

I am trying to install hubot-nagios4 module . Everytime i try installing with the command sudo npm install hubot-nagios4 --save  i get the below error. I am currently using node version 6.9.1 and npm version 3.10.1.

```
unameit@Unameit:~/node/example2$ sudo npm install hubot-nagios4 --save

> contextify@0.1.15 install /home/unameit/node/example2/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/home/unameit/.node-gyp/6.9.1"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/home/unameit/node/example2/node_modules/contextify/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1062:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:586:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-74-generic
gyp ERR! command "/mnt/node/node-v6.9.1-linux-x86/bin/node" "/mnt/node/node-v6.9.1-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/unameit/node/example2/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN example2@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-74-generic
npm ERR! argv "/mnt/node/node-v6.9.1-linux-x86/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "hubot-nagios4" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! contextify@0.1.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.15 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs contextify
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/unameit/node/example2/npm-debug.log
```

Please assist